# COM - Implementing DllGetClassObject

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, com

I am attempting to understand creating/using COM components without the help of MFC/ATL to know its inner workings.
I am using [this codeguru article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567/Step-by-Step-COM-Tutorial.htm%20this%20article) for reference.Following are the steps followed by me.

- Created a Wind32 Dll,
- Added a MIDL file and declared the interface `IAdd` and library name `DemoMath`; compiled the code using MIDL compiler.
- Created `CAddObj` class deriving `IAdd` interface,provided implementation for `IAdd` and `IUnknown` interfaces.
- Created class `CAddFactory` deriving from `IClassFactory` interface;provided implementation for `IClassFactory` methods.

Now creating `DllGetClassObject` to give client an option to invoke this function to get an instance of the class factory.

Following is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <objbase.h>
#include "AddObjFactory.h"
#include "IAdd_i.c"
STDAPI DllGetClassObject(const CLSID& clsid,
                         const IID& iid,
                         void** ppv)
{
    //
    //Check if the requested COM object is implemented in this DLL
    //There can be more than 1 COM object implemented in a DLL
    //

    if (clsid == CLSID_AddObject)
    {
        //
        //iid specifies the requested interface for the factory object
        //The client can request for IUnknown, IClassFactory,
        //IClassFactory2
        //
        CAddFactory *pAddFact = new CAddFactory;
        if (pAddFact == NULL)
            return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        else
        {
            return pAddFact->QueryInterface(iid , ppv);
        }
    }

    //
    //if control reaches here then that implies that the object
    //specified by the user is not implemented in this DLL
    //

    return CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE;
}
```

Now where is `CLSID_AddObject` constant suppose to be defined
 or Is it generated while compiling MIDL file(I didn't find it though)?

Comment: In many pre-C++98-standard compilers, `new` returned zero on failure. However, that hasn't been the case for over a decade, even on Microsoft's compilers. You need to catch the `std::bad_alloc` exception instead.

Comment: You have a memory leak in your `DllGetClassObject()` implementation. `QueryInterface()` increments the reference count if successful. If failed, your object does not get freed. You should start the object with a reference count of 1, call `QueryInterface()` on it, and then call `Release()` on it regardless of whether `QueryInterface()` succeeds or fails. That way, if successful, the reference count is only 1 (in the caller) when `DllGetClassObject()` exits, and if failed then the object gets freed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coclass` IDL item will typically get you CLSID:

```
library Foo
{
//...
    [
        //...
    ]
    coclass AddObject
    {
        //...
    };
```

then on your "IAdd_i.c" you are already including:

```
MIDL_DEFINE_GUID(CLSID, CLSID_AddObject, ...);
```

this is what defines `CLSID_AddObject`.

Comment: thanks for the answer,did u mean interface IAdd instead of IAddObject(since this does not exist) in coclass AddObject? and I assume there needs to be another uuid I should associate the coclass with,right?

Comment: `IAddObject` is irrelevant, just typical declaration. I updated to only leave the relevant part. `coclass` itself is the important thing.

Comment: @Hans Passant I didn't get why you removed your answer!